# Cucumber masterthought reports doesn't generate when build fails

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, bamboo

I am using masterthought [cucumber reports](https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting). The report generates only when there are no test failures (Build failure). I know I can use `<testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>` but don't want that since I want to fail the bamboo build when there are any test failure.

```
                <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <threadCount>50</threadCount>
                    <parallel>classes</parallel>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/CucumberRunner.class</include>
                    </includes>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904644/reports-are-not-generated-when-the-build-is-failed-in-maven-cucumber-reports/52206782#52206782