# Reports are not generated when the build is failed in Maven Cucumber Reports

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Reports are generating successfully when the build is successful but when there are any failed cases which cause build failure, reports are not generated.

**checkBuildResult** is already set to **false**

pom file plugin

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>execution</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <projectName>Simplify360 Automation Test Report</projectName>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/cucumber-reports</outputDirectory>
                    <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                    <!-- <jsonFiles>
                        <param>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</param>
                    </jsonFiles> -->
                    <!-- <parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting> -->
                    <buildNumber>8.4.1.2</buildNumber>
                    <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

And the runner class is as below,

```
  @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(
            features = {"classpath:features"},
            plugin = {"pretty","json:target/cucumber.json"},
            tags = {"@currentTest"},
            glue={"helpers","stepDefinitions"},
            monochrome = true
            )
    public class RunCukesTest{

    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the following configuration to the sure fire plugin. It will not stop the maven execution after the failure. Then it will generate the report.

```
<testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
```

as given below with your existing configuration.

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.20</version>
      <configuration>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: this worked. thank you. Can we send export these as PDF

Comment: I am not sure about export as pdf. may be you can try with extended cucumber report  here http://mkolisnyk.github.io/cucumber-reports/pdf-export

Answer (score 3):

There is flag present for same which is as below:

```
<checkBuildResult>true</checkBuildResult>

<!-- Set true to fail build on test failures -->
<!-- Set false to pass build on test failures -->
```

You need to set in the configuration tag as below:

```
 <configuration>
        <projectName>oasys-confirmations</projectName>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
       <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
       <checkBuildResult>true</checkBuildResult>
</configuration>
```

New config:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>3.20.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>cucumber-jvm-example</projectName>
                            <!-- output directory for the generated report -->
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                            <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                            <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/</inputDirectory>
                            <jsonFiles>
                                <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                                <param>**/*.json</param>
                            </jsonFiles>
                            <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                            <classificationDirectory>${project.build.directory}/</classificationDirectory>
                            <classificationFiles>
                                <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                                <param>sample.properties</param>
                                <param>other.properties</param>
                            </classificationFiles>
                            <parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting>
                            <checkBuildResult>true</checkBuildResult>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Old Config working till 3.16.0 version:

```
                 <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.19.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                        <version>3.16.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>execution</id>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>generate</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <projectName>>cucumber-jvm-example</projectName>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                    <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                                    <checkBuildResult>true</checkBuildResult>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

**NOTE** If you get same problem After this configuration then
1. Run RunnerFile Normally TestNG
2. Run Pom.xml  as Maven install.
3. Check target folder there is a TagName.html file open it and view the result.

Comment: @ShubhamJain it generates html report only while doing "maven install", generates only json report and doesn't update Html report while running as TestNG test. Any idea?