# maven cucumber report is not being generated

Tags: testing, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java

I've been trying to access the advanced reports in the cucumber mentioned in https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting I am using a maven project and my pom.xml and testrunner seem to be okay however in my target folder the advanced-reports folder never gets created. I can only see  the standard html file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>tHMApps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>thmapptesting</projectName>
                            <outputDirectory>target/cucumber-reports/advanced-reports.html</outputDirectory>
                            <cucumberOutput>target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json</cucumberOutput>
                            <buildNumber>1</buildNumber>
                            <parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java8 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/maven-cucumber-reporting -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>3.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.restassured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Above is my pom.xl file

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import cucumber.api.testng.CucumberFeatureWrapper;
import cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        glue = {"stepdefs"},
        tags = {"~@Ignore"},
        format = {
                "pretty",
                "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-pretty",
                "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json",
                "rerun:target/cucumber-reports/rerun.txt"
        }
)


public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

    @Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Feature", dataProvider = "features")
    public void feature(CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) {
        testNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(cucumberFeature.getCucumberFeature());
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] features() {
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideFeatures();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }
}
```

Above is my testrunner java file. Not sure what i am doing wrong for the reports to not be appearing

Comment: Have you executed `mvn verify`? see https://github.com/damianszczepanik/maven-cucumber-reporting

Comment: Sidenote: you're using a very old version of Cucumber. We're currently at v3.x. Please consider upgrading. If you do upgrade, note that the `<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>` was replaced with `<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>` as of v2

Comment: I upgraded my cucumber to the version you suggested! however i am now encountering java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class for the tests that were running before! i am not sure how to go from here as most of the info on this error is related more towards non-cucumber related topics

Comment: Solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904644/reports-are-not-generated-when-the-build-is-failed-in-maven-cucumber-reports/52206782#52206782

Answer (score 0):

Run mvn verify it will show verify all the dependencies and plugins are valid or not. I fixed the issue by doing the same. upon running mvn verify i got error failed to execute goal "generate" that is clearly pugn issue. Then i changed version of the plugin and report generated as expected.