# Maven-cucumber-report plugin not working

Tags: java, cucumber, pom.xml, maven-plugin

net.masterthought cucumber-reporting plugin is executing cucumber report is generating thats why it is not able to get the cucumber.json file at the given path.

in the pom.xml the phase is verify and goal is generate as below, I am not sure of the execution order to execute plugin after generating cucumber report.

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>(check version above)</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>cucumber-jvm-example</projectName>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                            <jsonFiles>
                                <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                                <param>**/*.json</param>
                            </jsonFiles>
                            <classificationFiles>
                                    <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                                    <param>sample.properties</param>
                                    <param>other.properties</param>
                            </classificationFiles>
                            <parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

If a remove this plugin then cucumber report got generated successfully. I want this maven reporting to execute after cucumber report generation.

Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldnt u add a version of the maven-cucumber-reporting to the pom instead of text? Can u add the cucumberoptions on the runner? Try commenting the jsonfiles, classi..files and parallel... with <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-json</cucumberOutput>. Also mention a sub-directory in the outputDirectory configuration like cucumber-report-etc-etc....

Comment: Solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904644/reports-are-not-generated-when-the-build-is-failed-in-maven-cucumber-reports/52206782#52206782