# maven-cucumber-reporting plugin is not generating the report - nothing happens

Tags: maven, cucumber, pom.xml

when adding the following plugin into my pom.xml, a report should be generated in my target folder, but nothing is generated. my project just runs and finishes without any report. Can someone look over this for any errors?

```
                 <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>execution</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <projectName>CucumberWebGui</projectName>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report-html</outputDirectory>
                                <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: Have you executed the Maven `verify` goal? Which Maven goal(s) you are executing?

Comment: @SubOptimal yes I have executed the verify goal, from the command line. When I look at the output, I don't even see maven executing that plugin, so I'm confused as to why bc this is quite straight forward

Comment: @SubOptimal the github instructions for net.masterthought does not reference any other changes besides pom (ie no change to runner). I don't understand why this works for everyone but me

Comment: It's not a problem of this plugin. You need to take care about that your specified input file `cucumber.json` for it is generated somehow. see my comment below my answer.

Comment: solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904644/reports-are-not-generated-when-the-build-is-failed-in-maven-cucumber-reports/52206782#52206782

Answer (score 11):

As you didn't show all configuration, I guess you might miss the `plugin` configuration in the `Runner` class. Find below a working project.

assume following structure

```
pom.xml
src/test/java/TestRunner.java
src/test/java/stepdefs/StepDefinitions.java
src/test/resource/features/demo.feature
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.suboptimal</groupId>
    <artifactId>cuke-test.so</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>CucumberWebGui</projectName>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report-html</outputDirectory>
                            <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**TestRunner.java**

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resource/features"},
        glue = {"stepdefs"},
        plugin = {"json:target/cucumber.json"})
public class TestRunner {
}
```

**StepDefinitions.java**

```
package stepdefs;

import org.junit.Assert;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;

public class StepDefinitions {
    @Given("^a successful step$")
    public void aSuccessfulStep() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("a successful step");
    }

    @Given("^a not successful step$")
    public void aNotSuccessfulStep() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("a not successful step");
        Assert.fail();
    }
}
```

**demo.feature**

```
Feature: Test cucumber reporting plugin

  Scenario: Run a non failing scenario
    Given a successful step

  Scenario: Run a failing scenario
    Given a not successful step
```

running `mvn clean test` will generate the Cucumber report file

```
target/cucumber.json
```

running `mvn verify -DskipTests` will generate the `cucumber-report-html` based on the `cucumber.json`

```
target/cucumber-report-html/cucumber-html-reports/src-test-resource-features-demo-feature.html
target/cucumber-report-html/cucumber-html-reports/...
```

running `mvn clean verify` will do all together

Comment: why does the plugin configuration in the runner only reference the json output and not the html?.....fyi, I do have the following in my pom - maven-surefire-plugin

Comment: @Time_is_an_illusion In the plugin configuration of `maven-cucumber-reporting` the option `outputDirectory` specifies the directory where the plugin will store its generated output, whereas the option `cucumberOutput` specifies the JSON file which is used as input by this plugin. This file needs to be produced somehow, for example by a Cucumber built-in plugin, therefore the option in the runner class. The option `json:` specify `cucumber.runtime.formatter.JSONFormatter` to be used. Which listen to Cucumber events and generate the output file. If you don't specify any plugin, you get no output

Answer (score 7):

Please try to use the below code snippet.Just give the path of json file in the   tag. In my case it is inside the target folder, so I used the below code and it working for me. Hope this helps!

```
 <configuration>
     <projectName>ExecutionResult</projectName>
     <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report-html</outputDirectory>
     <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</inputDirectory>
     <jsonFiles>
          <param>**/*.json</param>
     </jsonFiles>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

For integration test if you are using maven failsafe plugin, make sure that you have passed the environment variables inside the configuration of failsafe configuration because failsafe not pick any values from property-files like , junit-platform.properties, sample configuration is failsafe configuration follows

**failsafe**

```
               <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <environmentHost>localhost</environmentHost>
                            <environmentPort>8082</environmentPort>
                            <!--IMPORTANT :  failsafe plugin will not read any property files -->
                            <!-- It will ignore the values from junit-platform.properties, so you have to provide it-->
                            <spring.profiles.active>docker-integration-tests</spring.profiles.active>
                            <cucumber.filter.tags>@regression</cucumber.filter.tags>
                            <cucumber.plugin>html:target/jsonReports/cucumber-report.html, json:target/jsonReports/cucumber.json, junit:target/jsonReports/cucumber.xml, pretty</cucumber.plugin>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                        <parallel>none</parallel>
                        <classesDirectory>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</classesDirectory>
                        <classpathDependencyExcludes>
                            <classpathDependencyExcludes>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}</classpathDependencyExcludes>
                        </classpathDependencyExcludes>
                        <additionalClasspathElements>
                            <additionalClasspathElement>${project.build.outputDirectory}
                            </additionalClasspathElement>
                        </additionalClasspathElements>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>failsafe-integration-tests</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Assumes all your unit test class ends with `*Test.java`
and Integration Test runs with `*IT.java` and you are using cucumber for integration test ( i have not used surefire with cucumber report plugin so no idea it will work or not with the following conf.

Also in the `feature` file give the annotation `@regression` as 1st line for the cucumber to identify test during execution. Example follows

```
@regression
Feature: Wiremock the your controller for Integration test
```

now the cucumber report plugin from :

**net.masterthought**

plugin version : **5.4.0**

```
              <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-cucumber-reporting.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>execution-dwp-employment-income-api</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <!-- report generation is happening at this phase, so please dont change-->
                            <phase>integration-test</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <projectName>${project.name}</projectName>
                                <skip>false</skip>
                                <!-- output directory for the generated report -->
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jsonReports/reports</outputDirectory>
                                <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                                <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jsonReports</inputDirectory>
                                <jsonFiles>
                                    <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                                    <param>**/*.json</param>
                                </jsonFiles>
                                <mergeFeaturesById>false</mergeFeaturesById>
                                <!-- optional, set true to get a final report with latest results of the same test from different test runs -->
                                <mergeFeaturesWithRetest>false</mergeFeaturesWithRetest>
                                <!-- optional, set true to fail build on test failures -->
                                <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

now use `mvn post-integration-test` or `mvn verify` to generate the report. this is for integration test.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same issue and solved with this configurations.

- project folder structure

[image]

- pom.xml

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.techarchive</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumberReporting</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>cucumberReporting</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>
  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.13.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.9.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>6.9.1</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

  ```
  <build>
   <plugins>
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.8.1</version>
       <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
       </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.22.1</version>
       <configuration>
          <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
          <includes>
             <include>"**/Step*.java"</include>
          </includes>
       </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
       <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
       <version>5.6.0</version>
       <executions>
          <execution>
             <id>execution</id>
             <phase>verify</phase>
             <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
             </goals>
             <configuration>
                <projectName>web-cucumber</projectName>
                <!-- optional, per documentation set this to "true" to bypass generation of Cucumber Reports entirely, defaults to false if not specified -->
                <skip>false</skip>
                <!-- output directory for the generated report -->
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory} 
    </outputDirectory>
                <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory} 
    </inputDirectory>
                <jsonFiles>
                   <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                   <param>**/*.json</param>
                </jsonFiles>
                <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                <!--                   <classificationDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classifications</classificationDirectory> -->
                <!--                   <classificationFiles> -->
                <!--                      supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                <!--                      <param>sample.properties</param> -->
                <!--                      <param>other.properties</param> -->
                <!--                   </classificationFiles> -->
                <!--    <parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting>-->
                <!-- optional, set true to group features by its Ids -->
                <mergeFeaturesById>false</mergeFeaturesById>
                <!-- optional, set true to get a final report with latest results of the same test from different test runs -->
                <mergeFeaturesWithRetest>false</mergeFeaturesWithRetest>
                <!-- optional, set true to fail build on test failures -->
                <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
             </configuration>
          </execution>
       </executions>
    </plugin>
   </plugins>
   </build>
  </project>
  ```
- no changes were made in the feature, testrunner and steps.

Im using Eclipse IDE for generating report just follow this steps

- right click the project
- run as -> maven build

[image]

- verify and run

[image]

- make sure to **refresh** first the source code / project before checking the generated **cucumber-html-reports** folder

[Check the full code in github](https://github.com/earlhansg/web-cucumber/tree/T7-Reporting)